# Set a cron job every 45 minutes between 08 a.m. and 01 a.m

Tags: cron

I want to set a cron that execute an python script every 45 minutes between 08:00 and 01:00. Now I am using this command:

*/45 8-23,0-1 * * * script.py

But this command call the script at 08 , 08:45, 09, 09:45 etc
What I want is that the cron only call the script every 45 min (08, 08:45, 09:30, 10:15 etc)

How can I do this?

Comment: CRON won't do that. Instead, set CRON to run every fifteen minutes and have the script decide whether it has to do something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24355242/827263